# get_the_excerpt() not working in plugin loop

Tags: wordpress

I am new in WordPress plugin development. I am developing a simple WordPress plugin in which get_the_excerpt() not working in the loop. Other tags such as get_the_title(), get_the_permalink() even get_the_content() working fine. Please somebody help me out on this. Here is the code

```
 if($loop->have_posts()) : 
    while($loop->have_posts()) : 
          $loop->the_post(); 
   $content .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br />'.get_the_excerpt().'</li>';

endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif;
```

Comment: Can you try with `the_excerpt()` ?

Comment: I tried but didn't work

Comment: Have you given the excerpt in the backend for all that posts ?

Comment: Yes, I have given the excerpt in the backend for all that posts.

Answer (score 0):

> '.get_the_excerpt.'

the brackets are missing

```
'.get_the_excerpt().'
```

Comment: Sorry, actually they are not missing in real code. I just checked. I mistakenly didn't put them here. Edited.